# Clarifying an identity for random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

In this [note](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Etracy/courses/math135A/UsefullCourseMaterial/lawLargeNo.pdf) on the laws of large numbers, on page 4 the author comes to a sum of terms of the forms $E[X_i X_j X_k X_\ell], E[X_i^2 X_j X_k], E[X_i^2 X_j^2], E[X_i^3 X_k], E[X_i^4]$, where $X_i, X_j, X_k, X_\ell$ are IID random variables of mean $0$. They claim that all terms except the $E[X_i^4]$ and $E[X_i^2 X_j^2]$ vanish.

My question is: Why do those terms vanish, and why don't the other terms vanish? My understanding of independence is that a family $\{ X_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in A}$ is independent if for any collection $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \in A$ distinct, and for any sequence $F_1, \ldots, F_n \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, we have that
$$\mu\left( \left\{ \omega \in \Omega : X_{\alpha_1}(\omega) \in F_1, \ldots, X_{\alpha_n}(\omega) \in F_n \right\} \right) = \prod_{i = 1}^n \mu \left( \left\{ \omega \in \Omega : X_{\alpha_i}(\omega) \in F_i \right\} \right) .$$
However, I'm not sure how to turn this fact into a computation of integrals, and I'd appreciate any help with how to compute these expected values on the basis of independence. Thanks!

Comment: It is easy consequence of the fact that $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I think you shuold look at cases like $E[X_1X_2X_2X_3X_3X_3]$ etc to see what is happening.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I’ve heard that fact, but have yet to figure out how it’s shown, and also haven’t figured out how to tie that fact about products of two variables into this statement about multiple variables.

Comment: Example: $E[X_1X_2X_2X_3X_3X_3]=E[X_1]E[X_2^{2}]E[X_3^{3}]$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You’re coming across as very patronizing right now. Why can I do that when I only know how to handle $E[X_1 X_2]$ (a fact I already said I don’t even understand)? And why can’t I do it with, say, $E[X_1^2 X_2^2]$?

Comment: I appreciate that you’re trying to leave tips instead of outright answers, but I feel like I went to the trouble of saying in my question “I understand the definitions and would like help on how to use them”, and you’re just listing off the identities I’m trying to understand how to derive.

Comment: You can do that with $E[X_1^{2}X_2^{2}$ also. You get $E[X_1^{2}] E[X_2^{2}]$ and this is not zero. But $E[X_1] E[X_2^{2}E[x_3^{3}]=0$ because $EX_1=0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You still haven’t explained how I get that from $E[X_1 X_2] = E[X_1] E[X_2]$.

Comment: What you want is very difficult to prove from the ground up. I suggest looking at theorems 2.1.10, 2.1.12, and 2.1.13 in [Probability: Theory and Examples, by Durrett](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf).